# waitPID function not checking if the child process exited

Tags: c++, pipe, fork, waitpid

I am unable to get the `waitPid` to tell me if the child process exited or not.
In the parent process this is what I am doing:

```
if (forkID != 0) {
    
        pid_t result = waitpid(forkID, &status, WNOHANG);
        if (result == 0) {
          // Child still alive
            std::cout<<"Child Alive"<<std::endl;
        } else if (result == -1) {
          // Error
            std::cout<<"Error"<<std::endl;
        } else {
          // Child exited
            std::cout<<"Child Exited"<<std::endl;
        }

        DriverParser P;
        while (!std::cin.eof()) {

             std::string line;
             std::getline(std::cin, line);

              arguments = P.BeginParsing(line);
              if (arguments.size() > 0) {
                  for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                      finalArguments[k] = arguments[k];
                  }
                  
                  close(fd[0]);
                  write(fd[1],finalArguments,4*sizeof(int));
                  close(fd[1]);
                  
                  
                  
              }
         }
        
        
       // pid = wait(&status);
        
      //  std::cout<<waitpid(forkID, &status, 0)<<std::endl;
    

}else if (forkID == 0) {
   // child: reading only, so close the write-descriptor
    
    std::cout<<"I am child process my PID is: "<<getpid()<<std::endl;

    execv("./a.out", argList);
    
    // close the read-descriptor
    close(fd[0]);
    
   
    
}
```

I am basically sending the result of the parser as it reads from the stdin via pipe to child process, and then executing a process in execv. Now when this program exits using `exit(0)`  - I am not seeing `Child Exited` on the terminal which means the `waitpid` is  essentially not working for me.

What should I do?

Comment: You probably want to call `waitpid` in a loop if you use `WNOHANG`. Read the manual [here](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid).

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Should I use `waitpid` inside a while loop and check for the returned status?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `waitpid` with `WNOHANG`:

```
pid_t result = waitpid(forkID, &status, WNOHANG);
```

I shared with you the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid), which says:

> If WNOHANG was specified in options and there were no children in a waitable state, then waitid() returns 0 immediately and the state of the siginfo_t structure pointed to by infop is unspecified. To distinguish this case from that where a child was in a waitable state, zero out the si_pid field before the call and check for a nonzero value in this field after the call returns.

It also says:

> **WNOHANG**
> return immediately if no child has exited.

Considering that the call to `waitpid` happens immediately after fork, the chances are that the child is still running.

If you want to **wait** for the child process to end, just remove the `WNOHANG` option (pass `0` instead):

```
pid_t result = waitpid(forkID, &status, 0);
```